# URL rewrite with PHP and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Can anybody advise how I can rewrite the following URL:

```
www.mydomain.com/products.php?product=product-name
```

At the moment, it works fine (I use $_GET to grab the unique product name and use it on my page) but I would like to be able to use the following URL format to get the same outcome:

```
www.mydomain.com/products/product-name
```

I've seen a few similar examples on here but cannot get them to work with my situation.

Comment: This is fairly simple, have you tried any rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your **.htaccess** will look like,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)    /products.php?product=$1    [NC,L]
```

---

`RewriteEngine On` this is used to turn on the rewrite engine.

`^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` matches the URL like (www.mydomain.com/products.php?product=product-name) where product name can be one or more of any combination of letters, numbers and hyphens.

And use that combination of letters in `/products.php?product=$1` where `$1` denotes the Product name.